# "I wouldn't have said anything"

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

In *Desperate Housewives Season 1 Episode 1*, Julie (the daughter) told Susan (the mother) to ask Mike out. Susan said she didn't know if she's ready to start dating.

> SUSAN: I don't wanna talk to you about my love life anymore, it weirds me out.
>
> JULIE: **I wouldn't have said anything.** it's just...
>
> SUSAN: What?
>
> JULIE: I heard Dad's girlfriend asking if you'd dated anyone since the divorce, and Dad said he doubted it. And then both laughed!

What does the bold part mean? Is it part of 3rd conditional?

Answer (score 1):

"Said anything" means bringing up the subject (of Susan's love life).  Julie didn't want to (or knew she shouldn't) bring up that subject, *but* she did anyway.  She didn't say the reason explicitly here, but she implies that the information is important to Susan.

You can use this in any situation where you need to tell someone something that's awkward or embarrassing, but not telling them is now worse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I say "If the subject hadn't been brought by Dad and his girlfriend, I wouldn't have said anything"?

Comment: @samsam Yep, that’s exactly right.